# What is the proper term to describe the levels of experience for a trade?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

For the life of me I can't recall or even Google the proper term to describe the levels of experience for a given trade.

For example let's say there are 5 levels of experience to trade x:

- Rookie
- Journeyman
- Veteran
- Craftsman
- Luminary

What hypernym would describe these levels of experience?

Comment: If in any way this can help you narrow down your query, what I recall are apprentice, journeyman and master craftsman. This checks out well on a Google search as to the traditional structure of guilds.

Comment: Are you asking for a category word that includes all of "rookie", "journeyman", etc., or some sort of canonical listing of guild/trade ranks, or something else?

Comment: @Marthaª, yes I'm looking for a category word that would include all of those ranks

Comment: @TomRaywood  However, apprentice, journeyman and master were not levels of experience or skill but economic **roles**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I doubt there's any generally-accepted terminology, but in context, *grade, level,* or (more formally) *competence* would all be understood and accepted.

Answer (score 5):

This article on medieval [guilds](http://www.public.iastate.edu/~gbetcher/373/guilds.htm) calls them *stages*.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard them called *ranks* when talking about guilds (medieval and modern).

Answer (score 1):

[Based on innumerable and readily searchable examples from within online sources, e.g. "journeyman class",] the answer appears to be *classes*.

[Recommended edits in brackets]

Comment: This answer could be improved by a reference to a source where the word *classes* is used to describe some of these levels of experience. That is, why do you say it "appears to be" - where does it appear? (Because your answer was brief, it showed up automatically on the "low quality posts" area for review; you can avoid this by providing a little more information in your answers.)

Answer (score 0):

You might use **rank**

For example in the United States Navy:

> Enlisted: E-1 Seaman to E-9 Master Chief Petty Officer
>
> Officer via Enlisted Rank: Chief Warrant Officer 2-5 CWO
>
> Officer: O-1 Ensign to O-11 Fleet Admiral

Comment: Hey Melissa, I've edited your question to better formatting. The Stack Exchange formatting can take getting used to.